# Consulta MySQL desde una version 12.4.1

Tags: mysqli

Buen dia, trataré de explicar mi problema  lo mejor posible:

Esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM cargarol 
WHERE (IdOficina = 1100) OR (IdOficina <> 1100 AND IdOficina = 101)
```

Me trae los registros de ambas oficinas. Lo que quiero es que si selecciono **1100**, me traiga todos los registros que tenga la tabla. Por otro lado, si selecciono **101** solo me traiga los registros del mismo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?. He probado con *case*, *consultas anidadas* y no me da el resultado esperado.

Por otro lado,  si hago las consultas por separado, es decir, un simple `select * from cargarol`, me muestra todos los registros y si hago un `select * from cargarol where idofcina=101` me da solo sus registros, sin embargo, el problema es que si quiero hacer lo que antes escribí no puedo, es decir, tenerlo en un solo *select*.

Espero me puedan ayudar. Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Comment: Cuando dices *"selecciono 1100"* ¿A qué te refieres?. ¿Hay algún parámetro en la consulta?, por que en tu consulta no se puede distinguir entre valores parametrizados y valores fijos. Si usas la etiqueta [mysqli] tal vez deberías agregar tu código PHP.

Comment: buen dia, es un parametro. es como si quisiera hacer un if en una consulta de Mysql

IF (IdOficina = 1100) THEN
  SELECT *
  FROM cargarol;
ELSE
  SELECT *
  FROM cargarol
  WHERE IdOficina = 0101;
END IF;